# Visual Studio 2013, Intel INDE 2015 update 2, Platform IDS change while debug

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, opencl

I recently setup my system for opencl again.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Intel INDE 2015 update 2.

Until lately i used Intel INDE 2015 update 1.

Compiling is fine, debug also works.

I encountered a strange behaviour with update 2 now.
My platform ids change if i debug the code.

normal execution in visual studio debug compilation:

platform[0] -> intel cpu+gpu

platform[1] -> nvidia gpu 660 ti

If i Debug my code the following happens:

platform[0] -> nvidia gpu 660 ti

platform[1] -> intel cpu+gpu

Usage of Device IDs seems to be untouched
device[0] for intel CPU / nvidia gpu
device[1] for intel IGPU

This is quiet disturbing, because i allways have to change my code to debug the correct platform.

Has anyone encountered this strange behavior yet and found a solution?
I want to have the same platform ids with debug and normal execution.

Opencl 1.2 is used in all cases.
Also the visual studio command prompt closes even with strg+F5 execution since i installed the Intel INDE update 2. any solutions for this?

Comment: Don't use id's to get a specific platform. Use the returned string or a subset of it. Better yet, use the vendor id's to match the platforms.

Comment: thanks, i will try to change my code to do so. saves a lot of trouble